# Positioning a div at co-ordinates of another div

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a div inside which I have an anchor tag, on click of anchor tag I take its co-ordinates and using javascript I position another div next to it.
Below is my parent div.

```
<div class="parent1-div>
  <div class="parent2-div>
    <div class="child-div">
      <a (click)="anchorClickEvent($event)"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is another div, which I have kept separate so it can used elsewhere also,

```
<div class="movable-div" [ngStyle]="{'left': xPosition, 'top': yPosition}">
   This div contains some crazy animation
</div>
```

On click event:

```
anchorClickEvent(event: Event){
    this.xPos = event.currentTarget['x'] - somePx + 'px';
    this.yPos = event.currentTarget['y'] - somePx + 'px';
}
```

This gives me position relative to whole body, but I need the position of 'child-div' with respect to 'parent-div1', so I can set those position to 'movable-div'.

Inputs are appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: The whole DOM structure is not clear. Where is your `div.movable-div` placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue:
On click event I got the offset of anchor tag and subtracted offset of top most container i.e, 'parent1-div'.

```
anchorClickEvent(event: Event){
  this.xPos = Math.round(event.srcElement.getBoundingClientRect().left) - Math.round(event.srcElement.closest('.parent1-div').getBoundingClientRect().left) + 'px';
  this.yPos = Math.round(event.srcElement.getBoundingClientRect().top) - Math.round(event.srcElement.closest('.parent1-div').getBoundingClientRect().top) + 'px';
}
```

And added these styles dynamically to 'movable-div' element, which is position absolute relative to body.

```
<div class="movable-div" [ngStyle]="{'left': xPos, 'top': yPos}">
  This div contains some crazy animation
</div>
```